# How to detect a simple 2D chessboard with pieces on it?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, chess

My code so far can detect an empty chessboard, and it can also detect each piece. But I don't know how to put the two together.

My goal is to be able to recreate a chess game in real-time from images of the board (2-Dimensional).

The code won't detect a chessboard with **pieces** on it.

Input image:
[image: This is detected fine.]
Output image:

[image]

The above is fine with an empty board. However, `findChessboardCorners` will return `false` if I give it the same image as above, except with all pieces on the board.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def main():
    # Chessboard
    img = cv2.imread('/chess_main.png', 1)
    # Board detection
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, (7,7), None)
    print(ret)
    img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,7), corners, ret)

    cv2.imshow('detected', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Piece detection:
    # Thresholds to detect the pieces correctly (w = white, b = black)
    piece_threshold = {'bk': 0.5, 'bq': 0.6, 'br': 0.55, 'bb': 0.7, 'bn': 0.7, 'bp': 0.8,
                        'wk': 0.7, 'wq': 0.6, 'wr': 0.4, 'wb': 0.5, 'wn': 0.5, 'wp': 0.5}

    for piece, threshold in piece_threshold.items():
        # Loop over each piece
        piece_filename = '/{}.png'.format(piece)
        piece_template = cv2.imread(piece_filename, 0)
        width, height = piece_template.shape[::-1]
        res_piece = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, piece_template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        loc = np.where(res_piece >= threshold)
        # Draw rectangle around matching piece
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cv2.rectangle(img_rgb,pt,(pt[0]+width, pt[1]+height),(0,255,255),1)

    # Resize image
    img = img_rgb
    scale_percent = 50
    width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('detected', resized)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

main()
```

Is there a way to map an empty board to a board with pieces on it?
I'm not really sure what my next step should be. I need to build the coordinates of the board somehow.

Can anyone help with how to build the board?

Comment: Hello, if I understand well, you want to find similarities between pictures that will always look the same, right? Please do check for `HuMoments`, and also `cv2.matchShapes()`

Comment: @BBedit if you use the same image of the chessboard, save the coordinates of the corners of the chessboard, and make a mask with the small square size, then let the small square mask loop your chessboard 8x8 times, and detect each piece in each square, that seems to be simple if I understood you correctly.